# fastest way to compute angle with x-axis

Tags: c++, angle

What is the fastest way to calculate angle between a line and the x-axis?

I need to define a function, which is Injective at the PI:2PI interval (I have to angle between point which is the uppermost point and any point below).

```
PointType * top = UPPERMOST_POINT;
PointType * targ = TARGET_POINT;

double targetVectorX = targ->x - top->x;
double targetVectorY = targ->y - top->y;
```

first try

```
//#1
double magnitudeTarVec = sqrt(targetVectorX*targetVectorX + targetVectorY*targetVectorY);
angle = tarX / magTar;
```

second try

```
//#2 slower
angle = atan2(targetVectorY, targetVectorX);
```

I do not need the angle directly (radians or degrees), just any value is fine as far as by comparing these values of this kind from 2 points I can tell which angle is bigger. (for example angle in example one is between -1 and 1 (it is cosine argument))

Comment: Hmm, can't delete comments on my phone.

Comment: @Mooing SO on phone? where do you get a free data plan like that?

Comment: how can this be what I need? Imagine my top point is Origin.
Other points are for example a=[-10,-10] b=[-3,-5] and c=[-8,-5]. Sorted by angles: c,a,b Sorted by your method: b,c,a...

Comment: oh you deleted your comment, sorry

Comment: My phone has unlimited data, and the SO site is great on phones, except I can't delete comments, and a few other minor things.

Comment: I have 0.5 Gigs for about 7 dollars, I am extremely wary of extras =)

Comment: I also just noticed all those sample angles are in the range (PI, 2PI), instead of (0,PI) like I interpreted from the question.  @relaxxx, can you clarify the range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for y being zero as atan2 does; then The quotient x/y will be plenty fine. (assuming I understand you correctly).

Comment: -x/(y+.0001) may be faster, then you don't have to check for zero

Comment: It is doubles, put another 7-11 zeroes in there =)

Comment: I just realized you might not have to do anything special at all on machines with +inf and -inf.  They should sort correctly, right?  Maybe?

Comment: Division by zero is always messy regardless of arch.

Comment: In which case the amount added to the y should be a fraction of y, probably making the check for zero the faster option then.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote [Fastest way to sort vectors by angle without actually computing that angle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16542042/1468366) about the general question of finding functions monotonic in the angle, without any code or connections to C++ or the likes. Based on [the currently accepted answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16561333/1468366) I'd now suggest

```
double angle = copysign( // magnitude of first argument with sign of second
  1. - targetVectorX/(fabs(targetVectorX) + fabs(targetVectorY)),
  targetVectorY);
```

The great benefit compared to [the currently accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868162/1468366) is the fact that you won't have to worry about infinite values, since all non-zero vectors (i.e. `targetVectorX` and `targetVectorY` are not both equal to zero at the same time) will result in finite pseudoangle values. The resulting pseudoangles will be in the range [−2 … 2] for real angles [−π … π], so the signs and the discontinuity are just like you'd get them from `atan2`.