# Detecting unique Rooms (polygons) for a lista o Walls (lines) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, polygon

I have a script in javascript done to create points (Vertexes) and Walls (lines, connecting those vertexes).

My next implementation now requires me to that that array of Walls and find the unique polygons to detect if they create Rooms.

The data is already organized in a way that a Vertex is added to an array of Vertexes and the Walls have a "v1" and "v2" property that indicates what Vertexes they belong. "v1" and "v2" could be considered start and end, but the wall are created in chaos, meaning they may be done in any order, and so many walls can have the same v2 vertex.

I've made a sample data and how this data "draws" on screen. I've also manually colorized the image to demonstrate what would be considered rooms, but i'm strugling with a way to make it to an algorithim. Found some mathematical examples, but could not replicate a proper result.

The sample (a object with 2 arrays - 1 for Vertexes, 1 for Walls). The Vertex gains an id that is used by the wall to refer to then. I consider 2 Walls conected if the share a Vertex by the same id, in any way (v1 or v2, either v1 to v1, v1 to v2, v2 to v1 or v2 to v2).

```
{
    "vertices":
    [
        {"id":1,"x":401.9999999999999,"y":250.99999999999994},
        {"id":2,"x":531.9999999999999,"y":371.99999999999994},
        {"id":3,"x":595.9999999999999,"y":555.9999999999999},
        {"id":4,"x":781.9999999999998,"y":713.9999999999999},
        {"id":5,"x":1036.9999999999998,"y":713.9999999999999},
        {"id":6,"x":781.9999999999998,"y":828.9999999999998},
        {"id":7,"x":908.9999999999998,"y":885.9999999999998},
        {"id":8,"x":974.9999999999998,"y":830.9999999999998},
        {"id":9,"x":1146.9999999999998,"y":583.9999999999999},
        {"id":10,"x":1144.9999999999998,"y":808.9999999999998},
        {"id":11,"x":169.92891649440006,"y":347.2844582472},
        {"id":12,"x":636.5982877164412,"y":153.66702470084715},
        {"id":13,"x":720.9289164943999,"y":266.2844582472},
        {"id":14,"x":362.9289164944,"y":352.2844582472},
        {"id":15,"x":478.9289164944,"y":434.28445824719995},
        {"id":16,"x":478.9289164944,"y":581.2844582472},
        {"id":17,"x":245.92891649440006,"y":615.2844582472},
        {"id":18,"x":223.36547524631717,"y":460.65852263533225},
        {"id":19,"x":100.92891649440011,"y":553.2844582472},
        {"id":20,"x":185.92891649440006,"y":742.2844582472},
        {"id":21,"x":8.928916494400113,"y":742.2844582472},
        {"id":22,"x":-75.07108350559986,"y":657.2844582472},
        {"id":23,"x":-75.07108350559986,"y":484.28445824719995},
        {"id":24,"x":1.928916494400113,"y":365.2844582472},
        {"id":25,"x":726.5565877032943,"y":510.58901297277316},
        {"id":26,"x":837.9289164943999,"y":370.2844582472},
        {"id":27,"x":837.9289164943999,"y":192.2844582472},
        {"id":28,"x":742.9289164943999,"y":126.2844582472},
        {"id":29,"x":747.9289164943999,"y":202.2844582472},
        {"id":30,"x":747.9289164943999,"y":293.2844582472},
        {"id":31,"x":344.5320692909314,"y":670.9549979947822},
        {"id":32,"x":531.9289164943999,"y":631.2844582472},
        {"id":33,"x":691.6286174279545,"y":637.2329115785851},
        {"id":34,"x":550.8501387912459,"y":802.9594750369934},
        {"id":35,"x":287.9289164944,"y":802.9594750369934},
        {"id":36,"x":76.92891649440011,"y":861.2844582471998},
        {"id":37,"x":875.9289164943999,"y":560.2844582472},
        {"id":38,"x":680.9807883325162,"y":379.5585897817683}
    ],
    "walls":
    [
        {"id":1,"v1":1,"v2":2},
        {"id":2,"v1":3,"v2":2},
        {"id":4,"v1":4,"v2":5},
        {"id":5,"v1":4,"v2":6},
        {"id":6,"v1":6,"v2":7},
        {"id":7,"v1":8,"v2":5},
        {"id":8,"v1":9,"v2":5},
        {"id":9,"v1":10,"v2":5},
        {"id":10,"v1":1,"v2":11},
        {"id":11,"v1":1,"v2":12},
        {"id":12,"v1":2,"v2":13},
        {"id":13,"v1":12,"v2":13},
        {"id":14,"v1":14,"v2":15},
        {"id":15,"v1":15,"v2":16},
        {"id":16,"v1":16,"v2":17},
        {"id":17,"v1":17,"v2":18},
        {"id":18,"v1":18,"v2":14},
        {"id":19,"v1":11,"v2":19},
        {"id":20,"v1":19,"v2":20},
        {"id":21,"v1":20,"v2":21},
        {"id":22,"v1":21,"v2":22},
        {"id":23,"v1":22,"v2":23},
        {"id":24,"v1":23,"v2":24},
        {"id":25,"v1":24,"v2":11},
        {"id":26,"v1":3,"v2":25},
        {"id":27,"v1":25,"v2":26},
        {"id":28,"v1":26,"v2":27},
        {"id":29,"v1":27,"v2":28},
        {"id":30,"v1":29,"v2":30},
        {"id":31,"v1":30,"v2":13},
        {"id":32,"v1":29,"v2":12},
        {"id":33,"v1":12,"v2":28},
        {"id":34,"v1":20,"v2":31},
        {"id":35,"v1":31,"v2":32},
        {"id":36,"v1":32,"v2":3},
        {"id":37,"v1":3,"v2":33},
        {"id":38,"v1":4,"v2":33},
        {"id":39,"v1":33,"v2":34},
        {"id":40,"v1":34,"v2":35},
        {"id":41,"v1":35,"v2":31},
        {"id":42,"v1":35,"v2":36},
        {"id":43,"v1":36,"v2":21},
        {"id":44,"v1":33,"v2":37},
        {"id":45,"v1":37,"v2":26},
        {"id":46,"v1":25,"v2":38}
    ]
}
```

Ideally it would generate these Rooms (grouping the Walls involved):
[image: Correct Rooms]

In that case there would be 9 Rooms, ignoring Walls that don't end or branch out. Any inner Walls would form it's own polygon would be a Room by itself, so the area represented by the dark gray polygon would be a room, and the area by the light gray polygon would be another. The area of the dark gray polyon should not belong to the light gray polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you are standing next to a wall. You put out your right hand to touch the wall. Then you start walking, always keeping the hand on the wall. When you reach a vertex, you pick the leftmost wall leaving that vertex, as seen from the direction where you came from. Because that's the only wall you can go to without taking your hand off the wall; any other wall is behind the angle formed by the wall with which you arrived and the leftmost outgoing wall relative to that. Keep doing this until you reach the point you started from, i.e. with your hand touching the same wall from the same side.

Then analyze what you observed. You might have encountered walls twice, once from each side. In this case that wall was not containing any area. You can remove these walls, which may cause your loop of walls to split into multiple loops. Or it might cause a loop to disappear completely, if it only consisted of this one wall.

After that, you might find vertices which you visited more than once, with a different pair of walls on each encounter. That would be a pinch point in your loop, where multiple rooms meet in a point. Again you can split your loop at this vertex, always talking one outgoing edge and the next incoming edge after that, and connecting them to form a smaller loop.

Then look for any side of a wall that you haven't touched yet. This might be a wall you haven't touched at all, or a wall you only touched on the other side so far. Repeat the same exercise there, then continue picking new starting points until you have touched every side of every wall once.

After all of this you have a set of loops, each enclosing some non-empty area and having no duplicate walls or vertices. Some of them will follow an inside wall, with a counter-clockwise direction along the loop. These will this correspond to a single room. Some loops will correspond to an outside wall, with a clockwise loop direction. These might encompass multiple rooms that have inner walls on common, so these may be Jess useful to you. You can use the sign of a [signed area computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula?wprov=sfla1) to distinguish clockwise from counterclockwise traversal.

In the end you may need to investigate nesting, to remove inner rooms from the rooms around them. Or, if all you want is colour things in, you can sort loops by descending enclosed area (e.g. using the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula?wprov=sfla1)) so that smaller rooms get painted on top of larger rooms, ensuring a separate color.

To implement the above you might want to model each wall twice, once in either direction. Each “half wall” would holds a reference to its counterpart in the opposite direction, and an indication if it has been visited. Perhaps even when it has been visited, to tell whether opposite sides were encountered in the same or in different traversals. You might also want to keep a list of outgoing edges for each vertex, sorted by angle (or [pseudoangle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16542042/1468366)).

Comment: i'll try my best with it, got the idea, could not yet make it to a implementation - will study it, seems to have a proper concept.